# ¿Cómo elegir entre dos gestores de bases de datos en mi código VB.NET?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con VB .NET y necesito elegir entre dos manejadores de bases de datos en tiempo de ejecucipon (SQL Server y MySQL), en una clase (class_connection) tengo el código para abrir la conexión a la base de datos recibiendo como parámetro a que gestor debo conectarme:

```
Public class class_connection

Protected cnn

Public Function connection_open(ByVal DataBaseManagementSystem As String)

    Select Case DataBaseManagementSystem
        Case "SQL"
            cnn = New SqlConnection("connection_string_for_SQLServer")
        Case "MySQL"
            cnn = New MySqlConnection("connection_string_for_MySQL")
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("A database manager has not choosen! Please pick one in the main properties system form.", "ERROR.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
    End Select

    Try
        cnn.open()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try

End Function

End Class
```

Dentro de otra clase (class_functions) tengo la función que ejecuta la sentencia SQL (es un procedimiento almacenado). Esta función recibe también como parámetro el gestor de base de datos que se debe utilizar y devuelve como resultado un dataset con la información recolectada al formulario de trabajo:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class class_functions

Inherits class_connection

Dim cmd

Public Function show_data(ByVal database_manager as String) as DataTable

Try
    Call connection_open(DataBaseManagementSystem)

    Select Case database_manager
        Case "SQL"
            cmd = New SqlCommand("SQL_Stored_Procedure")
        Case "MySQL"
            cmd = New SqlCommand("MySQL_Stored_Procedure")
    End Select

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = cnn ' cnn variable has declared in class_connection '

    If cmd.Executenonquery Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Return (dt)
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        Call connection_closed()
    End Try

End Function
```

El problema se presenta en estas líneas:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = cnn ' This var is declared in the class_connection
```

Ya que el compilador trata la variabla 'cmd' como un 'objeto' y no permite el uso de los parámetros '.CommandType' y '.Connection' de los objeto SQLCommand()/MySQLCommand().

Mi pregunta es, cómo puedo solucionar este detalle?...

La razón por la que debo elegir entre los gestores (SQL/MySQL) es que en la configuración principal del sistema, se debe seleccionar con cual trabajar.

Comment: no alcanza con dim cmd as SqlCommand?

Answer (score 3):

Creo que tu aproximación es un poco compleja. Te comento lo que yo haría:

- Crearía una interfaz que se llame `IDatos` (por ejemplo). Esta interfaz definirá todos los métodos que necesites utilizar de acceso a base de datos.
- Luego te creas tantas implementaciones de esa interfaz como necesites. En tu caso, como mínimo, serían dos: Una para MySQL y otra para MsSQL. Por ejemplo `MySQLDatosImpl` y `MsSQLDatosImpl`.
- Finalmente, en tu código deberías siempre hacer referencia a la interfaz IDatos y tener una variable de tipo `IDatos` que usarás en tu código que será una instancia de `MySQLDatosImpl` o `MsSQLDatosImpl` según te interese.

Espero haberte ayudado.